# English wording for "first level of asymptotic expansion"

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

In French, we say that *$f$ est équivalente à $g$* denoted by $f \sim g$ for a limit point $x_0$ of a topology when $$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1.$$

This is the first level of [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)  in English. However it seems that the word **equivalent** cannot be used in English.

Is there an appropriate wording in English for "first level of asymptotic expansion"?

Comment: You would just say $f$ is asymptotic to $g$

Comment: You can say $f$ is asymptotically equivalent to $g.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rrr8 comment as an answer.

*You would just say $f$ is asymptotic to $g$.*